# Cassandra accessed from outside (9042-Cannot connect)

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Regards community,

I want to deploy a cluster of Cassandra DB on EC2 -AWS.

I followed these tutorials without problem: http://datascale.io/how-to-create-a-cassandra-cluster-in-aws/ http://datascale.io/how-to-create-a-cassandra-cluster-in-aws-part-2/

However my nodes (instances), can't be accessed from outside (DataStax DevCenter App / Linux CLI), although they have public IP and that the security group have the necessary ports open.

```
> The specified host(s) could not be reached. All host(s) tried for
> query failed (tried: /52.91.81.107:9042
> (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/52.91.81.107:9042]
> Cannot connect)) [/52.91.81.107:9042] Cannot connect My configuration
> file cassandra.yaml of node1:

cluster_name: ‘DataScale Demo Cluster’
seeds: “Public IP Node 1,Public IP Node 2”
broadcast_address: Public IP Node 1
listen_address:
```

I have doubts if I also need to modify the rpc_address (default localhost)?

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, you will need to modify `rpc_address` to your public IP.

Comment: post your cassandra.yaml file please

Comment: May be you can fix it by following the steps described in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724334/cant-connect-to-cassandra-nohostavailableexception/27738153#27738153)

Answer (score 0):

The listen_address and rpc_address should both be the private IP address.

Clients will then be able to access the cluster via the public IP address.