# Why I got NoHostAvailable:?

Tags: cassandra

if I run this simple query:

```
SELECT * from myapp.latests WHERE organization_id = 1 and user_id = 1;
```

I get error:

```
NoHostAvailable:
```

Running `nodetool status` results into:

```
Datacenter: eu-central
======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.0.53  190.96 KiB  256          0.0%              80f8bf0a-c46d-41ce-bb2e-498def5b3792  1a
UN  10.0.20.5  189.35 KiB  256          0.0%              f25fe4bf-29b2-4403-8e3e-4e973a5f26ab  1b
UN  10.0.0.54  183.13 KiB  256          0.0%              c46ac05a-6cb2-48f1-a776-2c57c33e7719  1a
```

And here is the description:

```
DESCRIBE myapp;

CREATE KEYSPACE myapp WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'eu-central-1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE myapp.locations (
    organization_id int,
    user_id int,
    date text,
    unix_time bigint,
    lat double,
    long double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((organization_id, user_id, date), unix_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (unix_time ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE myapp.latests (
    organization_id int,
    user_id int,
    lat double,
    long double,
    unix_time bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (organization_id, user_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724334/cant-connect-to-cassandra-nohostavailableexception
There can be many reason for this exception. This error message mainly indicates, client cannot connect to Cassandra host. Reason can be because host was down or your client code has some problem or connectivity to host is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that your client have permissions to connect on port 9042. 
If you are running it from cqlsh on cluster check that the port is open between Cassandra nodes (nodetool using another port and protocol (JMX) ).